# Prevent VNC session from locking screen

Tags: vnc

Is there a way to set a parameter with a VNC server session so that the screen doesn't lock due to a timeout?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be the target computer's desktop application (i.e., GNOME) which is causing the screen to lock, and not the VNC server itself.  Try to disable the screensaver or lengthen the idle duration on the target's desktop.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows versions VNC, the server software itself typically has a setting for whether to lock the screen on session termination. Screens-saver locks still apply regardless of VNC configurations. I don't think the VNC protocol allows the client to tell the server "don't lock the screen when I terminate," that's pretty firmly in the realm of security posture on the part of the server.